# read <td>-tag value from a scala for-loop created table

Tags: javascript, java, html, scala, playframework

I've created a table which displays person attributes like firstname, lastname, etc. To get those attributes of different persons I've used the scala for-loop to iterate through my person database.

```
<tbody>
        @for(person <- persons){
            <tr  class="odd gradeX">
                <form id="form1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username"  
                    value="@person.getUserName" id="user">
                    <td>@person.getUserName</td>
                    <td>@person.getFirstName</td>
                    <td>@person.getLastName</td>
                    <td>@person.geteMail</td>                             
                    <td>@person.getTelephoneNumber</td>
                    <td>@person.getBirthday</td>
                    <td>@person.getSvn</td>
                    <td>@person.getSalary</td>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="option" value="delete"
                        class="btn btn-danger" formaction="/admin
                        modifyPerson" formmethod="post">Löschen</button>

                        <button type="submit" name="option" value="reset" 
                        class="btn btn-warning" formaction="/admin
                        /modifyPerson" formmethod="post">Password 
                        reset</button>

                        <a href="#" onclick="changeData(@person, user)" form="form1" 
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeData">Daten 
                        ändern</a></td>
               </form>
          </tr>
      }

</tbody>
```

In the last column of the table the last "button" should start a javascript function "changeData()", which reads the table content and pass it to a bootstrap modal which displays a form to change the data. When the modal starts the form should be pre-filled with the table data.

My problem is the for loop. When I try to get the data from the table, I always get the values from the first entry no matter in which line I push the button.

Now I am trying to pass the whole person-object and the username, which is the ID in the database. Below the called javascript function:

```
onClick = changeData(@person, user)

<script>
        function changeData(person, user) {
            var allPerson = JSON.parse(person);
            var firstName = allPersons[0].getFirstName();

            document.getElementById("firstname1").value = firstName;
        }
</script>
```

Can I access to the passed person-object like `var fname = person.getFirstName();` or how can I get the attributes in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Change the onclick method to the following :

```
onclick="changeData(@person)"
```

This way you will get the person object specific to the row.And then use this to populate your modal.

Try the following :
In the script tag :

```
<script>
    var allPersons = JSON.parse(@persons);
</script>
```

This should initialize persons in your js scope.

Access this in your javascript in the following manner : 
    (function(user) {
        //access person over here
    })(persons);

This way you would get access to the persons object in your script.

As to getting a specific person object , from your changedData method pass the index of the object to your script and accordingly populate your form.

Note: I am not familiar with Scala, hence if any syntax mistakes or any such please look in the above lines .

Comment: thanks... how can I access this person object in javascript, like 
      var fname = person.getFirstName
the person object is written in java not javascript

Comment: is there no option to give the javascript method "changeData()" all the attributes as parameters?
or give each <td> tag an id, which I can give it to the method and get the value?

Comment: sorry i dont get it .. i am totally new to javascript/json ..  lets say i want the firstname.. so I have to call the getFirstName() java-method.. how would the code look like after the "var allPersons = JSON:parse(@persons);" line to get the firstname of the given person?

Comment: Inside the function block I have suggested, try this. : 'var firstPersonName=allPersons[0].personName; '

Comment: Inside this block : (function(allPersons) { 
})(allPersons);